# Laravel 7, várias variáveis na mesma View

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

Bom dia, 
estou a desenvolver um pequeno projeto em Laravel 7 e estou com uma pequena dificuldade. É a primeira vez que utilizo foreign key e várias variáveis no mesmo Controller e na mesma View index. Até ao momento já consegui criar as tabelas de Base de Dados com a foreign key e penso que no Controller está tudo correto, pelo menos não dá erros, mas na View index está a dar erro a partir do momento que começo a utilizar a segunda variável, "Trying to get property 'data_type' of non-object", é este o erro que dá ao carregar a View index no Browser.

No código da View index é isto que tenho,

```
@foreach($forms as $form)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $form->name_form }}</td>
        <td>{{ $form->description }}</td>
        <td>{{ $form->email }}</td>
        <td>{{ $form->end_date }}</td>
        <td>{{ $form->question->data_type }}</td>
        <td>{{ $form->question->question }}</td>
        <td><a href="{{route('forms.edit', $form->id)}}" class="btn btn-info">Editar</a></td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Será que alguém me consegue ajudar, é a primeira vez que contacto com várias variáveis na mesma View e não estou a conseguir corrigir o erro.

Comment: Poderia colocar o método do seu controller responsável por retornar essa view?

Answer (score 1):

A sua variável `$form->question` não é um objeto e vc não consegue acessar propriedades dela usando a seta referencial `->`.
Verifique o tipo dessa variável e se ela realmente está vindo ou está nula;`

Faça um `dd($form->question)` e verifique o que está vindo da controller;

**possível solução 1 - a variável está nula:**

substitua as linhas abaixo:

```
<td>{{ $form->question->data_type }}</td>
<td>{{ $form->question->question }}</td>
```

por:

```
@if(!empty($form->question))
    <td>{{ $form->question->data_type }}</td>
    <td>{{ $form->question->question }}</td>
@endif
```

**possível solução 2 - a variável é um array ao invés de um objeto:**

substitua as linhas abaixo:

```
<td>{{ $form->question->data_type }}</td>
<td>{{ $form->question->question }}</td>
```

por:

```
@if(!empty($form->question))
    <td>{{ $form->question['data_type'] }}</td>
    <td>{{ $form->question['question'] }}</td>
@endif
```